# Writing Bearer Token to Javascript

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, bearer-token

I'm trying to do a Proof of Concept. I'm using Azure Active Directory and trying to implement OAuth in a legacy project.

Half of this project is using Web Forms, the other half is calling WebAPI in another project directly through javascript.

As a test, I obtain the Bearer Token though the AuthorizationCodeReceived notification event of the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication.  I quickly write the token to a page that is calling the WebAPI with the following code:

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: baseVotingHeaderURL,
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function(xhr){
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            options.success(result);
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            options.error(err);
                        }
                    });
```

I can see in Fiddler that the token is being passed:

No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
Authorization Header is present: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (I've obviously substituted the token with X's)

I'm still getting an Unauthorized 401.

Why doesn't this work?

Below is the code from Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType( CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType );
app.UseCookieAuthentication( new CookieAuthenticationOptions( ) );

app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication( new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Tenant = "XXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    AuthenticationType = "OAuth2Bearer",
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters( )
    {
        ValidAudience = "https://XXXX.onmicrosoft.com/XXXXX"
    }
} );

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://XXXXXXX/gbl/Home.aspx",
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse( );
                    context.Response.Redirect( "/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message );
                    return Task.FromResult( 0 );
                },              
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                {
                    var client = ClientId;
                    var key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=";                               

                    var credential = new ClientCredential( client, key );
                    var authority = String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", "XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com" );
                    var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext( authority );

                    Uri redirectUri = new Uri( HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart( UriPartial.Path ) );
                    var apiResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
                    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            context.Code, redirectUri, credential, apiResourceId );

                    EndpointAndTokenHelper.DecodeAndWrite( result.AccessToken );
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( result.AccessToken );

                    return Task.FromResult( 0 );
                }
            }
        } );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following the examples verbatim. However, the final parameter in the authContext.AquireTokenByAuthorizationCode should have been my WebAPI resource and not https://graph.windows.net.

I don't know why the examples use https://graph.windows.net.

Comment: the examples use the graph because that is the API they want to call.

Comment: I thought Graph was another endpoint in Azure AD that was needed to query more information about the user.

Comment: It is - but as such, it is a resource that requires a token to be accessed: requesting that token follows the same "laws of physics" that apply to all other API protected by Azure AD, and that includes specifying the resource identifier

Comment: ahhh... Got it! Thanks!!